# how to append to file with cordova-plugin-file

Tags: javascript, cordova, append, filewriter, cordova-plugin-file

I'm trying to append text to a file.

I have followed tutorial of [Html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) as suggested by plugins's github page.

I've sucessfully created a file and wrote to it. But when im trying to append text, i got a write success event but no text is added. I'm only able to change characters but no characted added to the end. It's not an async issue, i'm also trying live test with chrome's js console. Im also using `fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length)` before trying to write at the end. (but seek(0) to write a the beginning)

there is the module i wrote :

```
'use strict';

function File_mgmt(name) {
    var name = name;

    var myfile = '';

    var next_write = '';

    var that = this;

    var errorHandler = function (e) {

        var msg = '';

        switch (e.code) {
            case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
              msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
              break;
            case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
              msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
              break;
            case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
              msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
              break;
            case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
              msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
              break;
            case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
              msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
              break;
            default:
              msg = 'Unknown Error';
              break;
        };

        console.log('Error: ' + msg);
    };


    var init = function() {
        console.log("init");
        request(gotFS);
    };

    var gotFS = function() {
        console.log("gotfs");
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function(dir) { 
            dir.getFile(name, {create:true}, function(file) {
                myfile = file;
            }, errorHandler);
        });
    };

    this.write = function (data) {
        myfile.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

            fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
              console.log('Write completed.');
            };

            fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
              console.log('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
            };

            // Create a new Blob and write it to log.txt.
            fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length);

            fileWriter.write(data);

        }, errorHandler);


    };

    this.reopen = function() {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function(dir) { 

            dir.getFile(name, {create:false}, function(file) {
                myfile = file;
            }, errorHandler);
        });

    };

    this.getfile = function() {
        return myfile;
    };

    this.writeTextBlob = function(data) {
        this.write(new Blob([data], {type: 'text/plain'}));
    };

    var request = function(success){
        var fail = function() {console.log("failed to initialise system")};
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 1024*1024, success, fail);
    };  

    var writer = function() {

        myfile.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

            fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
              console.log('Write completed.');
            };

            fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
              console.log('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
            };

            // Create a new Blob and write it to log.txt.
            fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length);

            fileWriter.write(next_write);

        }, errorHandler);
    };

    this.testWrite = function(data) {
        next_write = data;
        request(writer);

    };


    init();


    return this;

}
```

I'm using it with chrome console with

```
var f = new File_mgmt("test");
f.writeTextBlob("test1");
f.writeTextBlob("test2");
```

---

### Edit

I've tried to pass by a `window.requestFileSystem()` to append but it still doesnt work, I've also updated my code.

now i'm doing

```
var f = new File_mgmt("test");
f.testWrite("test1");
f.testWrite("test2");
```

Comment: Aren't you allocating 0 space here: `window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);`

Comment: By the way are you using cordova or phonegap to be exact?

Comment: Piwwoli, I'd tried but i got same result.. may be i sould run this before trying to append ?

i'm using cordova 5.0.0 as shown by `$ cordova -v`

Comment: Isn't whole cordova undefined, unless you are running it on a mobile device?

Comment: yes, i'm running it on android device and debugging it with remote chrome ..with chrome://inspect

Comment: Is someone can, at least confirm this bug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's appearing than my file actually got new data.  I had to unplugged then replugged usb cable to see the new data appened to my file.

May be it's a problem with Windows.  I'll look if i got the same problem on linux.

Comment: That's correct!! You're really awesome man! Thanks.
In linux that's working as expected, but in Windows 7 you need to do this as a Workaround because you don't have any choice than this!